# Python/Tk: Entry widgets in frames on separate rows are linked

Tags: python, tkinter

I have encountered an issue using Tk with Python 2.6. I have a GUI that is automatically built from xml code using a Python wrapper. Everything is fine apart from a section which consists of the following layout:

Row 1: [Label1] [Button1] [Frame1a[Label][Entry]] [Frame1b[Label][Entry]]

Row 2: [Label2] [Button2] [Frame2a[Label][Entry]] [Frame2b[Label][Entry]]

The problem is that, for some reason, if I enter a value in Frame1a[Entry] in Row 1, the number I enter is also copied to Frame2a[Entry] in Row 2. Likewise for Frame 1b/2b. I checked the frames when I initially create and populate them with widgets, and they are all individual frames with the only linking element being the first parameter, self.root. Also, I add them to the main window using frame.grid().

Does anyone know of a circumstance when this would happen? I can post code if required, although I'd prefer not to. I have searched around, but no-one else appears to have had this issue.

Thanks

EDIT: Posting some code

```
def new_frame_setup(self, name, options, row_idx=0):

    label   = tk.Label(self.root, text=name, font=("Helvetica", 16))

    _master_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, borderwidth=1, relief="ridge")
    for edit_idx in xrange(len(options)):
      _sub_frame = tk.Frame(_master_frame, borderwidth=1, padx=5, relief="ridge"))
      _sub_frame.grid(row=0, column=edit_idx)
      tk.Label(_sub_frame, text=options[edit_idx][0]+options[edit_idx][1], width=5, font=("Helvetica", 16)).grid(row=0, column=2*edit_idx)
      s = tk.StringVar()
      s.set('%s' % (row_idx))
      tk.Entry(_sub_frame, textvariable=s, text=options[edit_idx][2], width=10, font=("Helvetica", 12)).grid(row=0, column=2*edit_idx+1)

    button  = tk.Button(self.root, text='GoGoGo', font=("Helvetica", 12), command=None)
    self._frame_layouts.append([label, _master_frame, button])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen if the generated code assigns the same variable to the `textvariable` attribute of two or more entry widgets.

Comment: I actually had not defined textvariable for the Entry widgets. I just tried by creating a new StringVar() each time, assigning it a unique number, and it still happens. I'll post some code and maybe someone will spot an obvious error.

Comment: Bryan, you were actually right (as I'm sure you are aware!). The fact I had used the `text` parameter overrode the use of `textvariable`, and when I checked the xml code I was indeed assigning the same number. Removing the `text` parameter fixed the problem. Thanks!